# For loop for multi plot

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

I looked in the internet and also in this website but I didn't found a solution, so sorry if my question has already been answered.
I have a dataframe in which several rows have the same ID. Let's say for example

```
ID   Value1  Value2
P1    12      3
P1    15      4
P22   9       12
P22   15      14
P22   13      9
P30   10      12
```

Is it possible to write a script that take the dataframe and plots in different pages Value1~Value2, for every different ID? In other words I'd have 3 plots, in which value1 is plotted versus value2 for P1, P22 and P30.

I try to write a script with a loop (but I'm a really newby of R):

```
for (i in levels(dataset$ID)) {
 plot(dataset[i,2], dataset[i,2])
}
```

But I receive the errors:

```
Errore in plot.new() : figure margins too large
Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Comment: The statement you have `plot(dataset[i,2], dataset[i,2]` must be a typo - you are printing data "against itself" so you would at best plot a straight line. Also you don't close the parenthesis of the `plot` command. Can you check and edit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `by` here , to group your data by ID. Note Also that I use the ID for the title. If you'don't have a lot of ID , maybe a facet approach , suing a more high level plot package, as shown by @Roman is better here.

```
by (dataset,dataset$ID,function(i){
  plot(i$Value1,i$Value1,main=unique(i$ID))
})
```

Note also this don't deal with you "Errore" ( I guess Spanish for Error )

```
Errore in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

Generally When I get this error, with RStudio, I enlarge my plot region. Otherwise you can always set your plot margin using something like , before the call to the plot loop:

```
 par(mar=rep(2,4))
```

Comment: I tried but it returns:                                         Errore in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Comment: @matteo You can see my edit. I add explanation for your error.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this.

```
mydf <- data.frame(id = sample(1:4, 50, replace = TRUE), var1 = runif(50), var2 = rnorm(50))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydf, aes(x = var1, y = var2)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ id)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me what you mean by "in different pages". Pages of a PDF? Then run the code in the comments too.

```
DF <- read.table(text="ID   Value1  Value2
P1    12      3
P1    15      4
P22   9       12
P22   15      14
P22   13      9
P30   10      12",header=TRUE)


#pdf("myplots.pdf")
for (i in levels(DF$ID)) {
  plot(Value1 ~ Value2,data=DF[DF$ID==i,])
}
#dev.off()
```